# Translate website and internationalization

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, translate

I have an application in **ASP.Net** in **AngularJS**, until then that my application had the need only in Brazil, but recently the company where I work needs to make this site available to other countries in other languages ​​like Spanish and English.

I have never worked with International applications, so there will be many doubts and difficulties.

I'll start with the difficulties: 
- My application has **fixed texts** in the **html, database and code**, how can I translate all these fronts? Is there a component that translates everything into the client? (Javascript, AngularJS, etc ...). 
- Development time for this change (Too much code to change).

Questions: - Decimal, Date and Time, how to work with these values ​​in an International application? (My application has many logs and values ​​to display and insert)

I'm researching a lot but really needed a hint of where I could go.

Thank you, I'll wait!

Answer (score 0):

I would start searching for "Localization". There is something called "AspNetBoilerplate" that has implemented localization into there project. Here is their link: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/ and here is document on how to use it within their project: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Localization. You can easily download a free project and see what they did to implement it.

They have different localization files based on language being used. The language being used is a setting in the DB based upon the tenant that logs in. All static text looks up to its respective localization file (See their .Core project under "Localization" to see all their files).

As far as DateTimes/Decimals/etc, I would have extension methods that looked up the cached localization being used and format respectively.

By no means am I recommending you use this software but rather see how they implemented it within their project. Also, know that I have only had to do this once and there may be numerous other ways to accomplish this goal.

Comment: I think I did not express myself very well.
My application is asp.net only, but the homepage is a single page made in AngularJS.
My application has several points with static words that are in HTML, Code Behind (Web Api Self-hosted) and database, are several points that I would need to have a considered development effort, so there is no component that acts in the client (javascript, jquery and etc ...) that translates the entire site without my having to use Resources.
This would be the ideal scenario, but there I would have other challenges in the database such as Time zone and currency.